# Why ref and out are not sufficient to disambiguate overloaded in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, methods

For example, why this method `Max(ref int x, ref int y)` is not considered overload of `Max(int x, int y)`? Why is the same with `out`?

Comment: But they are sufficient. If you hat included some code that would have been clear.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This question presupposes a false premise.

```
 Max(int x, int y)
 Max(ref int x, ref int y) 
 Max(out int x, out int y)
```

are all overloads of a method named `Max`. However, note that only one of the last two may be present in any given class definition. From the specification §3.6:

> **The signature of a method consists of the** name of the method, the number of type parameters and the type and **kind (value, reference, or output) of each of its formal parameters**, considered in the order left to right. For these purposes, any type parameter of the method that occurs in the type of a formal parameter is identified not by its name, but by its ordinal position in the type argument list of the method. The signature of a method specifically does not include the return type, the `params` modifier that may be specified for the right-most parameter, nor the optional type parameter constraints.

[...]

> Although `out` and `ref` parameter modifiers are considered part of a signature, members declared in a single type cannot differ in signature solely by `ref` and `out`. A compile-time error occurs if two members are declared in the same type with signatures that would be the same if all parameters in both methods with `out` modifiers were changed to `ref` modifiers. For other purposes of signature matching (e.g., hiding or overriding), `ref` and `out` are considered part of the signature and do not match each other. (This restriction is to allow C# programs to be easily translated to run on the Common Language Infrastructure (CLI), which does not provide a way to define methods that differ solely in `ref` and `out`.)

Comment: Note that the last 2 overloads are mutually exclusive

Answer (score 4):

`ref` and `out` are the same thing, symantically. The CLR does not differentiate between the two. The C# language is making the distinction. For the CLR, there is only `ref`.

Comment: Although the ref and out keywords cause different run-time behavior, they are not considered part of the method signature at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The language designers decided to create it that way.

I *suspect* (and this is just my opinion) that it was due to the fact that `ref` and `out` must be specified to reduce confusion.  The language could have easily be designed to not require explicitly specifying `ref`/`out`, and have the compiler do it implicitly, but that would cause confusion.  Similiarly, making these overloads would prevent other languages from being written that way (since the CLR is not just C#), and would just add to the overall confusion by many users, and it would be less clear which method is being called.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write some code:

```
static void M1(int y)
{
    Console.WriteLine("val");
}

static void M1(ref int y)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ref");
}

//static void M1(out int y)  // compile error
//{
//    Console.WriteLine("out");
//}

static void Main2()
{
    int a = 3;

    M1(a);
    M1(ref a);
//    M1(out a);

}
```

Ther only is a conflict between the `ref` and `out` versions. Comment out the `out` parameter method and it compiles and runs as expected: Output is `val` and `ref` .

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Max(int x, int y)          
//No Error
public void Max(ref int x, ref int y)  
//No Error
public void Max(out int x, out int y)  
//cannot define an overloaded method that differs only on parameter modifiers 'out' and 'ref'
```

First and second method can be overloaded.
But the second and third method cannot be overloaded because **both ref and out are treated differently at run time but they are treated the same at compile time**.